# Why crossorigin attribute matters for preconnect links?

Tags: html, cors

I understand preconnect tells a browser to perform DNS lookup, TCP connection & TLS handshake(in HTTPS) with a given host. All of of those processes are done, prior to sending any HTTP packets, although HTTP version might be negotiated during TLS handshake(ALPN).

I believe that crossorigin attribute affects the following:

- **No crossorigin attribute**: Origin header is not sent, because of which server never sends Allow-Control-Allow-Origin header which can enable CORS.
- **anonymous mode**: Origin header is sent & CORS can be enabled, but Cookies & authentication are not sent during a request.
- **use-credentials mode**: Origin header is sent together with Cookies & Authentication header, which may enable CORS.

Origin, Cookies & Authentication are sent in HTTP request, after DNS+TCP+TLS was already established. In such case, why would crossorigin attribute matter during preconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS client certificates.

The browser can authenticate itself to the server not just in HTTP headers when sending a request (at the application layer), but while still establishing a TLS session (at the transport-ish layer), using a client certificate.  This requires the browser to know whether such authentication should be performed or not.

This is specified in the HTML Standard and in the Fetch Standard.  As of this writing (October 2022), [preconnecting](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#preconnect) is specified as directing the browser to [obtain a connection](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-connection-obtain), which in turn is defined in terms of [creating a connection](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#create-a-connection), which in step 2 chooses whether to use a certificate based, ultimately, on the CORS credential policy setting specified in the `crossorigin=` attribute.  TLS certificates are currently the only authentication mechanism that CORS credential policy influences at the connection stage.

Comment: This is correct, but we also purposefully create different connections based on whether the requests going over it will include credentials or not. So day-to-day this will be more about cookies and less about TLS client certificates. (https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/341 has some discussion about potentially changing that, but not a lot of recent activity.)